# How to format to a specific pattern with Log4j?

Tags: log4j

I want to capture the log4j logging comments in the following way. Is it possible ? If so then how should my log4j.properties look like ??

My Message : 2009-05-22 17:07:28

Thanks
Rink

Answer (score 7):

Use the following conversion pattern: `"%m: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}%n"` without the quotes.
If you wanted to use ConsoleAppender, your `log4j.properties` file would contain:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, CON
log4j.appender.CON=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CON.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CON.layout.ConversionPattern=%m: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}%n
```

Answer (score 3):

Add following lines in your log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=MyMessage : %-5p %d{yyyy-MMM-dd   HH:mm:ss,SSS} %m %n

log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=MyMessage : %-5p %d{yyyy-MMM-dd   HH:mm:ss,SSS} %m %n
```