# How to get time in ISO format from LoggingEvent?

Tags: java, log4j, jms

I'm sending logging events using JMSAppender. In `Receiver` I need to print them/put into a file - with date in format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS
```

but I can only do `event.getTimeStamp()` which returns `long`.

(I find it strange, because in regular logging, using `%d` we cannot log current time in milliseconds)

Is there any way to get date in ISO format from logging event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905666/how-to-format-to-a-specific-pattern-with-log4j?rq=1

Comment: @adarshr I cannot set it in `properties` file. I use JMSAppender and I'm sending **events**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
DateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
String dateString = dformat.format(new Date(event.getTimeStamp()); 
System.out.println(dateString );
```

Comment: I've tried, it works, thank you! Is it time consuming? (In case I have a lot of logs it can be a problem)

Comment: You can have the DataFormat initialized once and reuse it I suppose. But I am not sure .. it probably is not thread safe. So How many threads do you have for logging? In case you have mutiple pooled threads for logging .. may be you can just define the DataFormat as a ThreadLocal Variable and get going. Depends on how you use it.

Comment: My idea was to gather some logs sent by JMSAppender from distributed system and pass them to file/database/console/log viewer. Probably I could store date in millisecond, but my log viewer (ChainSaw) cannot process this format.